# How to remove Sharepoint and Reporting Services from TFS 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, tfs, tfs-2015

We’re running TFS 2013 Update 1 and I’m planning an upgrade to TFS 2015 Update 1.

We have both SharePoint and Reporting Services installed and configured for TFS that *I like to remove, because nobody ever uses them.*

So, do I simply uncheck both Reporting and SharePoint during the TFS 2015 upgrade wizard. Is this the best way to do it?

Or, do I un-configure Sharepoint and Reporting Services first from our TFS 2013 installation? If so, what are the steps to do so?

Environment:

Server computer A:

- Application tier for TFS 2013 Update 1
- Data tier: SQL Server 2012 SP 1 for the TFS databases, and Reporting Services databases
- Sharepoint services (only for TFS)

Server computer B:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 hosting the SharePoint databases.

Answer (score 5):

You can do either.

I'd probably uninstall/disable first if you're really sure you don't want them in the future (check with all the teams that they're not storing docs in SharePoint as they will lose them).  That way the backup will be smaller/faster when you backup before you upgrade (Make sure you take a backup!!).

It's simple enough to do, just fire up the TFS Administration Console.
Select Reporting, Edit (this will stop the jobs) and uncheck "Use Reporting".  Click OK.

For SharePoint, click SharePoint Web Applications and under the top section, click Modify against your server connection and choose Remove.

[image: TFSAdmin]

Make sure you take a new backup at this stage and then you can start the upgrade.

Some things to consider:

Are you sure you want to do this in-place?  You could clone the server to new hardware and test the upgrade first or perform a migration upgrade.  It means less downtime in the event of something going pear shaped.

If your collection(s) are large, this is likely going to take a long time.  The 2015 upgrade seems to be slower than previous upgrades due to all the schema changes.

Are you sticking with a single server?  That's fine, but you won't need server B for SharePoint so you could move to a dual server TFS install if capacity is a problem (You'd need to upgrade the SQL version on server B to act as a data tier though)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do it in-place but of course testing would be desirable (I did do that ages ago when doing a migration from TFS 2012 to 2013, but this time I'm considering skipping it...).

The collection isn't large I guess (22 GB).

Comment: Small word of warning. I did this and it went fine, but when creating a new project I was faced with an error that it couldn't access the reporting services. I had to open the TFS admin console and view the `Reports Folder` tab of a team project collection so it would forget it was configured at all. I guess the info was cached for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a couple years late, but this still popped up in a search result so worth mentioning - use cmd prompt to do this:
Navigate to %programfiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server %#%\Tools\, and type `TfsConfig.exe setup /uninstall:SharePointExtensions` .  This will "unconfigure" the feature in your App Tier.