# How to un-configure, remove or uninstall non-needed Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, reporting-services-2012

I just have un-configured Reporting Services from TFS 2013 because we never used it (see [How to remove Sharepoint and Reporting Services from TFS 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180095/how-to-remove-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-from-tfs-2013)).

Now my SQL Server 2012 is running services that I we don’t need anymore: Reporting Services (including its IIS site) and maybe also Analysis Services (not sure if that is useful in SQL server for other purposes?).

I want to make sure that there aren’t any leftover jobs or other settings for those services that still attempt to analyze the TFS data (and just use server resources or potentially generate errors in the Event Log).

Is there anything I need to do to clean up to make sure that SQL Server Analysis Services or Reporting services don't (attempt to) do any work on the TFS databases?

Can I / should I stop the services (and maybe disable them) or uninstall them? What are the steps for that? Or maybe don't bother and leave everything as is?

Answer (score 0):

1). You can delete Tfs_Analysis cube from Analysis Services, and also delete Tfs_Warehouse database.

2). As 'Use Report' is disabled in the TFS Administrator Console, no jobs will analyze or sync data for TFS reporting purpose.

3). You can either stop or uninstall the Reporting Service. For uninstall Reporting Service, please check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479745.aspx
and stop Reporting Service, please check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157232.aspx