# disable reporting TFS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

We have assumed maintenance of a legacy 32bit application.  I installed TFS 2008 to use in maintaining the project.

We will never use reporting or sharepoint.  I cant create a project because of issues with SSRS.

*(The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while creating reports on the SQL Server Reporting Services on OHSENSS801. The reason for the failure cannot be determined at this time. Because the operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish creating the SQL Server Reporting Services site. )*

How can I disable reporting and sharepoint in TFS 2008?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you insist on using TFS2008?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike  TFS 2010 and above version, you have to install the SharePoint components for TF2008.

TFS2008 is a very old server version and out of support for a long time. You could use TFS2010 instead,  **the SharePoint is no longer a prerequisite when you install TFS2010**. You can go for TFS2010 Basic Configuration which is the most compact TFS installation possible.

In Basic Configuration, SharePoint and Reporting Integration will not be possible. It will install and configure Source Control, Work Item tracking and Build Services only.

Highly recommend you to move to a newly versioned TFS server. If you insist on using TFS2008, you could try to troubleshoot the configuration of SQL Server Reporting Services. Details please refer this thread in MSDN: [SQL Server Reporting Services is not configured correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248632.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

About how to remove Sharepoint and Reporting Services from TFS, you could go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180095/how-to-remove-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-from-tfs-2013). However, afraid removing these components, you will still not able to create team project. After all, if it will work, there is no need to be a prerequisite for installing TFS2008.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if 2010 would work with 32 bit code.  I worked with TFS 2008 back in the day and had the install disk lying around so I went with that.  From what I read sharepoint & SSRS COULD be disabled but I guess it's a big issue.

I'll try the basic 2010 install & see what it does.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can load VS 2008 32 bit projects into TFS 2010?

Comment: @JohnDMP To make  Version Control available for VS2008 and TFS2010, you need to add  MSSCCI provider. Details please refer the Client compatibility is this page:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#client-compatibility , From it you could also find TFS2008 is really out of date and support :)