# TFS 2017 & earlier disable SharePoint integration

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

What will be the steps to disable and completely remove SharePoint integration on TFS 2017? Currently the documentation shows how to "Disable SharePoint integration after TFS 2018 upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

- Go to TFS Administration Console.
- Click SharePoint Web Applications.
- Click Modify against your server connection.
- Choose Remove.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2018 and later versions no longer support native integration with SharePoint products.

With TFS 2017 & earlier you could still configure and use TFS-SharePoint integration, if you don't need the sharepoint feature any more. You could simply **remove sharepoint** feature.

For SharePoint, click SharePoint Web Applications and under the top section, click Modify against your server connection and choose Remove.

More details please take a look at this similar question: [How to remove Sharepoint and Reporting Services from TFS 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180095/how-to-remove-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-from-tfs-2013)